# How to set layout for UIButton in storyboard for different states?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

Is there a way how to customise `UIButton` in interface builder for different states of that button?

Comment: yes, of course:-) it is possible. At the bottom, while you creating the question, there is a checkbox: "answer your own question". This is under "share your knowledge" program:) you can use it if you want. I vote your answer up.

Comment: Well, the thing is that there is a huge amount of answers for this question already. I don't know if it would be necessary to open a new question for this.

Comment: @MasterRazer: self-answering is [actively encouraged behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Provided the question and answer are otherwise fitting the site rules, of course. If you think this is a duplicate, you are welcome to flag it as such.

Comment: @MasterRazer: and by flagging, I meant you find a suitable canonical post and flag this post as a duplicate of that post. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I consider leaving this question not marked as a duplicate, because surely there are plenty answers to set each UIButton property via IB. However, there isn't a question which asks to set all UIButton propertys via IB.

Comment: @MasterRazer: then don't, that's up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, let's say this is the **default** state:

[image]

Now let's change the title for `highlighted` state:

[image]

This is how it looks before I press the button:

[image]

...and after:

[image]

You can do the same for **every** property of the button.

**Note:** `default` and `highlighted` states are controlled automatically, but `selected` and `disabled` you have to control manually.